# Touchpad madness

Tags: cursor

Is anyone else having 'mouse' trouble on controlling a laptop touchpad?  The cursor becomes uncontrollable.  I used to own a floppy disc with these tricks for fun; but this has come to my machine unwelcomed and with malice.  I suspect entry-by-cookie; but no system setting or AVG virus scan will detect or get rid of it.
As you guessed, I'm no 'SuperUser'.  There MUST be a simple toggle somewhere.  Paleeeze help.

=  Ancient Dell Inspiron 1100 running XP,SP2
=  CPU 2.2 Ghz; 256MB RAM

It's hard enough to milk this machine as it is!  But it's all I got.

Answer (score 2):

I would find this on hot days when my hands were a bit clammy, or if I'd just been washing dishes and my hands were damp. Once a little bit of moisture got onto the touchpad it would be unusable for ages. My latest computer doesn't seem to have this problem so much.

...or maybe it's because I don't wash dishes any more... ;)

Comment: Thanks, Rob.  Between Toledo & Houston, I've learned clammy.  This just 'feels' like malicious code insinuated somehow.  =jb

Comment: I live in Adelaide, Australia. It was 40C yesterday.

Comment: How presumptious and rude of me to be so geocentric.  And what does that "C." stand for again?  Must be a hemisphere thing...

Comment: Celsius. 40C = 104F

Answer (score 0):

download and install the **[latest driver](http://www.synaptics.com/support/drivers)** for your Synaptics touchpad.

post back if the error persists.