# How to fix touchpad drift?

Tags: touchpad

My MSI Wind touchpad started drifting towards bottom-left corner, when untouched. It's useless, the cursor runs away before I click on a selected point. I suspect hardware problem, it has been unstable since the beginning.

Reading between the lines [here](https://superuser.com/questions/98963/touchpad-madness/98971#98971), I realized that it might be moisture. Is there a way to fix this without taking the whole thing apart? (Warranty is void already due to upgrade, but I would have to unscrew the mother board.) How to handle this anyway, if the disassemble is necessary? Should I use alcohol or something different?

Is there another possible cause?

I tried to use a blower brush on external case surface without success. The device looks clean: no dust, no grease.

EDIT: I looked inside and found no signs of damage. The touchpad area is actually just an imprinted in a case, so no moisture could have gotten there.

**SOLVED:** It turned out to be software problem. After installing a driver (`xf86-input-synaptics`), the touchpad not only behaves, but also gets scroll and tap features. The problem was that the default driver seemed to work at first not raising my suspicion.

Answer (score 1):

In my experience, this is usually caused by the pointer device, not the touchpad. It is for that reason that I have disabled the Pointer device.

Comment: No external pointer device is connected.

Comment: I meant the button nestled in the keyboard that also moves the cursor. If you don't have one, then my advice is inaccurate. Regards,

Comment: I don't have a track point either.

Answer (score 0):

I have seen this before when a touchpad was cleaned with a spray furniture polish and I suspect the anti-static properties of the polish left a conductive coating across the surface which messed up the pad's operation. The fix was to rub down the pad with some lotion-free baby wipes followed by a damp paper towel and then a dry towel to remove all moisture. May not apply in your case, but a good clean may help.